# It says 5.7 is a security release - should I upgrade?

Tags: civicrm-home

"I thought we were on the latest security release but I'm seeing references to a Security Release (when logged in)?"

[image]

Answer (score 2):

No worries - from this popup I can tell you are on the latest CiviCRM security release -> 5.3.1 - the Extended Security release is not more secure than 5.3.1

Comment: You can blame me for the confusion, I think I suggested the Extended Security Release name.

Comment: Just documenting this as I answered this question 3x today.